# C: Implementation of a Quicksort algorithm with pointers

Tags: c, algorithm, pointers, quicksort

I'm trying to implement a Quicksort algorithm in C language with pointers, but I found that I get problems in the function:

```
int partition(int *a[], int start, int end, int pivot_idx)
```

For example, if I want to sort an array of 3 items:

```
4 3 2
```

when I enter the function partition in the while:

```
while  (a[high_idx]>pivot)
```

with `high_idx = 2`, `a[high_idx] = 2`, `pivot = 3`, the condition `2 > 3` results in `true`, and so the execution continues, but it shouldn't be like this. I think that I should resolve the problem with the function `malloc`, but I'm fledgling with pointers and I need your help.

Can anyone help me?

```
void swap (int **ptr_s1, int **ptr_s2)
{
    int *temp;
    temp=*ptr_s1;
    *ptr_s1=*ptr_s2;
    *ptr_s2=temp;
}

int partition (int *a[], int start, int end, int pivot_idx)
{
    int low_idx=0, high_idx=0;
    int *pivot;

    pivot= a[pivot_idx];
    swap(&a[pivot_idx], &a[start]);
    low_idx=start+1;
    high_idx=end;
    while(low_idx<=high_idx){
        while(a[high_idx]>pivot){
            high_idx--;
        }
        while((a[low_idx]<=pivot)&&(low_idx<=high_idx)){
            low_idx++;
        }
        if(low_idx<high_idx){
            swap(&a[low_idx], &a[high_idx]);
            low_idx++;
            high_idx--;
        }
    }
    swap(&a[high_idx], &a[start]);

    return high_idx;
}

void sort (int *a[], int start, int end)
{
    int pivot_idx, new_pivotidx;
    if(start<end){
        pivot_idx = (start+end)/2;
        new_pivotidx = partition(a, start, end, pivot_idx);
        sort(a, start, new_pivotidx-1);
        sort(a, new_pivotidx+1, end); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You say "*the condition 2>3 results true and it continues to work but it shouldn't be like this*". What should be done then? I think you're on good tracks there. No `malloc` would change anything on the algorithm.

Comment: Probably `int *a[]` --> `int a[]`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY and so `int *pivot` --> `int pivot` too :)

Comment: @Daniela Favia "the condition translates to 2 > 3, so results in true" - till now I have thought that the result is false.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow My mistake, I edited it as "grammar" change but in fact it was wrong. I reverted that.

Comment: [DEMO](http://ideone.com/8m2P3O)

Comment: The condition 2>3 should fail and it should pass at the second while condition **((a[low_idx]<=pivot)&&(low_idx<=high_idx))**, i.e. **((3<=3)&&(1<=2))**. Referring to int *a[ ] I used it because the exercise asked to use an array of pointers.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY does the program work with your modify?

Comment: So `a[low_idx]<=pivot` : To be a comparison of the value is not a comparison of the pointer.

Comment: Given that `a[high_idx]`, `a[low_idx]` and `pivot` are all `int*` (**pointers** to ints), you should compare the integers behind them with `* a[high_idx] > * pivot` and `* a[low_idx] <= * pivot` — your comparisons compare the pointers, i.e. the addresses where the numbers are stored, not the numbers themselves. This is why you appear to get 2 > 3: 2 is stored at a higher address than 3.

Comment: Ok guys, thank you a lot! Now my program works right and you have been very clearly in your advices. So, when I have to compare two pointer items, I have to compare the pointers and not the integers behind them. Thank you all!